# Solving $x^2 + y^2 = M$ over integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, sums-of-squares

In the last few days, I have been wondering about the following equation in $x,y \in N$: $$x^2+y^2 = M$$ with $M \in N$. More precisley, I don't understand how can we compute the number of solutions that this equation have and especially how can we find it.

I've tried to use the formula: $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$, but it looks me like as another complication, especially because I've to do this calculations for large value of $M$. I've also read the post [Integer solutions to $x^2+y^2=N$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93316/integer-solutions-to-x2y2-n), but it hasn't really helped me alot.

Any ideas or suggestions? Are there also sites which I can consult on this topic? Thanks.

**ANOTHER QUESTION (not already answered)**

If using the above formula, we can find the solutions to $x^2+y^2=M$, what if M is a very large prime (such as $M=10000000103$): do I have to do only bruteforcing?

**EDIT:**
As suggested, I have read the page on Wolphram Alpha linked above in the comments, but I still not uderstand in what way we can find the solutions of $x^2+y^2=M$. For example take the case: $x^2+y^2=85$ has $r_2(85)=16$, buit how can we obtain the value of $(x,y)$?

Comment: See the [Sum of Squares Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html)

Comment: If $M$ is large and we do not know the factorization, we won't be able to find such a representation in general.

Comment: @Peter: $0\leq M \leq 10^8$, so it isn't completely impossible to find the factorization.

Comment: OK, for so small $M$, this is absolutely routine.

Comment: I've read the page on Wolphram Alpha, but I'd like to have some examples? Can someone provide them? Thanks.

Comment: The mathworld page that lulu linked to has examples for $M=4,5$.  It also has an explicit formula for the number of representations if you know how to factor $M$.  If you search this site for sum of two squares you get a lot of hits.  I can't find an exact duplicate among them

Comment: If $x^2+y^2=M\le10^8$, and $0\le x\le y$, then $x<x_{max}=\sqrt{5\times10^7}$, so you can just ask your computer to test, for each $x$ from zero to $x_{max}$, whether $M-x^2$ is a square.

Comment: @Meyerson: yes, I can do so, but it would be extremely slow.

Comment: How hard is it to test $7000$ numbers to see which ones are squares?

Comment: In the case that $M$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$ then it is **not** a sum of two integer squares. A Fermat theorem.

Comment: @Matteo "Extremely slow" ? I would agree if you would deal with , lets say , $20$ digit numbers. But in the case of $10^8$, I fully agree with Gerry Myerson.

Answer (score 2):

Given $x^2+y^2=85$, and the well-known factorization formula [which you already obviously know] $$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) = (ac\pm bd)^2+(ad \mp bc)^2.$$

Now just work backwards:

1. Factor $85=5 \cdot 17.$
2. Note that each factor (*i.e.*, $5$ and $17$) have representations as the sum of two squares: $5=4+1=(\pm 2)^2+(\pm 1)^2$ and $17=16+1=(\pm 4)^2+(\pm 1)^2$.
3. Determine $x$ and $y$ from $(a,b,c,d)$, going through all possible permutations (including multiple signs).

Comment: @MacMillan: thanks, and in case of numbers with more than two factors?

Comment: How do you know that there isn't some rational non integer $(a^2 + b^2)$ that matches integer values for $(\dots)^2 + (\dots)^2$ ?

Comment: @Matteo: Say $n= p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot p_3$, where the $p_i$ are all prime factors. You simply make $a^2+b^2=p_1 \cdot p_2$ and $c^2+d^2 = p_3$ and apply the same principle inductively.

Comment: @DanielV: Because it’s been proven (cf. Carmichael _et al._).

Comment: How do we know that the algorithm is generating all solutions ?

Comment: @Thomas: For one proof, see Carmichael’s _Diophantine Analysis_, Section 10 Lemma III (<https://www.gutenberg.org/files/20073/20073-pdf.pdf>, p. 33).

Answer (score 0):

This is in general a very hard problem because any
method which finds solutions to
$\, n = a^2+b^2 = c^2+d^2\,$ allows us to
factor $\,n.\,$
However, factoring large numbers is a very
hard problem according to Wikipedia
[Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

Using [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) we have that
 $\,a^2 + b^2 = (a+bi)(a-bi)\,$ and if we
can find that
 $\,n = a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2,\,$ then we
must have that
$\, n = (a+bi)(a-bi)=(c+di)(c-di).\,$
Find the $\,g := \gcd(a+bi,c+di) = e+fi\,$
using the Euclidean algorithm.
Now we have that $\,(e+fi)|(a+bi)\,$ and hence
 $\,(e^2+f^2)|(a^2+b^2).\,$ 
But now $\,e^2+f^2\,$
is a factor of $\,n.$

Comment: But OP is only interested in numbers up to $10^8$.