# Solving $x^2 + y^2 = M$ with $M$ prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

This question is related with the topic: [Solving $x^2 + y^2 = M$ over integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506267/solving-x2-y2-m-over-integers)

I have understood the formula used to determine $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=M$ with $M$ composite. But what if $M$ is a large prime such as $M=1000000241$ do I have to do only bruteforcing? Are there other methods?

**EDIT:**

I know that $M$ must be a prime of the form $4k+1$ but how to find $(x,y)$?

Thanks

Comment: But your $M$ is equal to $3$ modulo $4$.

Comment: It's a simply example of $M$.

Comment: For any such numbers we can get an answer immediately. Think about this.

Comment: I changed the number to an actual prime (as suggested by OP’s original statement).

Comment: This is Fermat theorem that primes can be written as sum of two squares if and only if $p=4k+1$. Your  M satisfies this condition.

Comment: it's $7700^2+30671^2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Have you found it by bruteforcing?

Comment: I found it with Wolfram alpha

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/efficiently-finding-two-squares-which-sum-to-a-prime is a prior question which discusses some methods in the answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently finding two squares which sum to a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/efficiently-finding-two-squares-which-sum-to-a-prime)

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is that, yes, brute force is [currently] your only real recourse for large primes.

The good news is that primes which are the sum of two squares have a unique representation in that form… so once you find **a** representation, you’re done.

Comment: And what for a smaller prime $M$?

Comment: you can actually sieve out a lot. it's just you can't tell which part is which one must be nonzero mod 3, one must be odd, one must be 1 or 4 mod 5... etc.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 + y^2 = M$ represents a circle with $(0,0)$ as its center and $\sqrt{M}$ as its radius.

So once you plot this circle on a Cartesian system, then you should be able to find all values of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy your equation.

(I'm assuming you're allowed the use of a graphing calculator.)