# A circle in the plane contains at most four lattice points?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $\cal C$ be a circle in ${\mathbb R}^2$ : 
$\cal C=\lbrace (x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2 | 
(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2\rbrace$ for some
constants $x_0,y_0,r$.

What is the maximal number of points 
that can be contained in ${\cal C}\cap {\mathbb Z}^2$ ?
I conjecture it is $4$, attained for the "trivial" case
$x_0=y_0=0,r=1$.

Comment: It can have more - e.g. a circle of radius $\sqrt{5}$ contains 8 points. I believe this number can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: There are integers which are sums of squares in several ways.  $50$, for example, is $7^2+1^2$ or $5^2+5^2$.

Comment: I note that if a circle passes through three points in $\mathbb{Q}^2$, then the center of the circle is also in $\mathbb{Q}^2$. So we do not lose much generality by saying that the $x_0$ and $y_0$ are rational. Or in fact, by taking $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: If you are interested in whether individual numbers of lattice points can be attained (rather than whether there is an upper bound), then you _do loose_ generality by assuming $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$: for that point as centre, the number of lattice points must be a multiple of $4$ for symmetry reasons (but for other centres it does not; see also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81079/18880)).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Interesting. By lattice points I suppose you mean points in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$? Do you know what natural numbers $n$ are attainable as lattice points (in this sense) on a circle (whose center can have irrational coordinate(s))? If instead we count the number of points in $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, my argument shows (I think) that if that number is finite but exceeds $2$, then it is a multiple of $4$. But do you know what numbers $n$ are attainable as the number of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ points on a circle?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Curious, I would think that your argument almost shows that if a circle contains at least three rational points, it contains infinitely many of them (the reflection interchanging a given pair of points is rational; I don't think two such reflections can generate a group of finite order except in very simple cases). For the attainable numbers of lattice points I'm sure all even numbers are attainable. But I think I've seen once that all odd numbers are as well, though I forgot the argument.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Google found a book (by W. Sierpinski, some pages available for free from Google Books) where they give explicit circles with exactly 0, 1 and 2 rational points. Then they complete "my" proof that a circle with more rational points than that must have an infinity of them. They translate to center $(0,0)$. Then since there exists one rational solution $(a,b)$ to $x^2+y^2=r^2$, they use that $a$ and $b$ to write $x=\frac{2at+b(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}$; $y=\frac{a(1-t^2)-2bt}{1+t^2}$, so just like in M. Bennet's answer below. They remark that the rational points on it form a dense subset.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The unit circle centred on the origin can be parametrised by $$x=\frac {1-t^2}{1+t^2}; y=\frac {2t}{1+t^2}$$

Any rational value of $t$ gives rational values of $x$ and $y$. This can be scaled by a factor $r$ to give a circle of radius $r$.

Choose $n$ such points, and then choose a radius which clears all the denominators - the resulting circle will have at least $n$ integer points.

Comment: This is probably the most elementary solution. Very nice

Comment: Interesting, what about a unit sphere?

Comment: **A unit sphere** is a sphere with a radius of 1. **The unit sphere** is a unit sphere with it's center at the origin. Not entirely logical but who ever said mathematicians are always logical?

Comment: @JohnM The unit sphere centred at the origin includes a unit circle in the $x,y$ plane, and therefore all the rational points on the unit circle - and these can be scaled to integer points.

Answer (score 29):

There is no upper bound. On the circle:

$$ x^2+y^2 = 5^k $$
there are exactly $4k+4$ lattice points. That follows from the fact that the number of representations of $n$ as $x^2+y^2$ is given by four times a multiplicative function that depends on the number of divisors of the form $4k+1$ and the number of divisors of the form $4k+3$.

Answer (score 13):

There is no upper bound. Take the product of, for example, several consecutive primes that are $1 \pmod 4,$ and let $r = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 29.$ Find all Pythagorean triples with that hypoteneuse $r.$ Those all occur as points on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$